# Encryption of files with checksum and decrypting them

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I need some help with encryption and decryption of files with Javascript:

I have the following encryption functions, this will take the path of the source file and the destination path of the resulting encrypted file as parameters. It also adds a checksum to verify data integrity:

```
function encryptAndMoveFile(sourcePath, destinationPath) {
  try {
    const iv = randomBytes(16);
    const fileCipher = createCipher(iv);
    
    const sourceData = readFileSync(sourcePath, 'utf8');

    const checksum = createHash('sha256').update(sourceData).digest('hex');

    const encryptedData = Buffer.concat([fileCipher.update(sourceData), fileCipher.final()]);

    const encryptedChecksum = createCipher(iv);
    const encryptedChecksumBuffer = Buffer.concat([encryptedChecksum.update(checksum, 'utf8'), encryptedChecksum.final()]);

    writeFileSync(destinationPath, iv);
    appendFileSync(destinationPath, encryptedData);
    appendFileSync(destinationPath, encryptedChecksumBuffer);

    console.log('Encr iv', iv.toString('hex'));
    console.log('Encr check', encryptedChecksumBuffer.toString('hex'));

    console.log('File encrypted and moved successfully.');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error', err);
  }
}

function createCipher(initializationVector) {
  return createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(ENCRYPTION_KEY, 'hex'), initializationVector);
}
```

On another part of my code, I perform the decryption function, this will return the contents of the encrypted file and take the path of the encrypted file as parameter:

```
async function decryptFile(filePath) {
  try {
    const encryptedData = readFileSync(filePath, 'binary');

    const iv = Buffer.from(encryptedData.slice(0, 16), 'binary');
    const data = Buffer.from(encryptedData.slice(16), 'binary');

    const decipher = createDecipher(iv);
    
    const decryptedData = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(data), decipher.final()]);

    const decryptedChecksum = decryptedData.subarray(-64);
    const decryptedDataWithoutChecksum = decryptedData.subarray(0, -64);

    console.log('Decr iv', iv.toString('hex'));
    console.log('Decr checksum', decryptedChecksum.toString('hex'));

    const checksum = createHash('sha256').update(decryptedDataWithoutChecksum).digest('hex');
    console.log('Deigested checksum', checksum);

    if (checksum !== decryptedChecksum) {
      console.log('Error');
    }

    const decryptedContent = decryptedDataWithoutChecksum.toString('utf8');

    return decryptedContent;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error: ', err);
    throw err;
  }
}

function createDecipher(initializationVector) {
  return createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(ENCRYPTION_KEY, 'hex'), initializationVector);
}
```

My only issue here is that the checksum that gets generated during encryption (`decryptedChecksum`), the `decryptedChecksum` and the `checksum`  are completely different, preventing a correct checksum validation. What can I do to solve this issue?

As an example, I tried with a random text file with 'utf8' encoding, and the resulting encrypted file gets encoded either with 'utf16le' or 'ANSI' encoding. This happens regardless of the file size.

Comment: I can see you're reading the source file with `utf8` encoding and then writing it to the destination file with `binary` encoding. Can that be the probable issue?

Comment: During decryption, ciphertext and encrypted checksum must be decrypted *separately*. In addition, regarding the checksum, padding must be taken into account. If you do this, decryption and checksum check are successful.

Comment: Note that your implementation contains a number of vulnerabilities. You should stick to common practices (encrypt-then-MAC, using an HMAC, etc.) and not invent new algorithms, see e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202). Besides the vulnerabilities, your implementation is also inefficient.

Comment: @Topaco can you please write an example as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ciphertext and checksum are to be decrypted separately. Regarding the checksum the padding is to be considered.

A possible implementation of decryption is e.g.:

```js
...
const encryptedData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'binary');

// Separate IV, ciphertext and encrypted checksum
const iv = Buffer.from(encryptedData.slice(0, 16), 'binary');
const ciphertext = Buffer.from(encryptedData.slice(16, -64 - 16), 'binary');    // regarding the checksum: consider padding
const encryptedChecksum = Buffer.from(encryptedData.slice(-64 - 16), 'binary'); // regarding the checksum: consider padding

// Decrypt ciphertext
const decipher = createDecipher(iv);
const decryptedData = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(ciphertext), decipher.final()]);

// Decrypt checksum
const decipherChecksum = createDecipher(iv);
const decryptedChecksum = Buffer.concat([decipherChecksum.update(encryptedChecksum), decipherChecksum.final()]);
const decryptedChecksumHex = decryptedChecksum.toString('utf8');

const checksumHex = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(decryptedData).digest('hex');
if (checksumHex === decryptedChecksumHex) {
    return decryptedData.toString('utf8')
} else {
    return "Decryption failed...";
}
...
```

---

*Security:* You should not implement your own algorithms, but use proven concepts for authenticated encryption. Usually, the MAC is not generated for the plaintext, but for the ciphertext. This has the advantage that no decryption is necessary in case of failed authentication, see e.g. [*Should we MAC-then-encrypt or encrypt-then-MAC?*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202).
Instead of an encrypted digest, an HMAC makes more sense, see also [*AES256 CBC + HMAC SHA256 ensuring confidentiality and authentication?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5235161/9014097) for more details.
Keep in mind that today there are modes of operation that *implicitly* perform authenticated encryption, e.g. GCM, see also [*What is the difference between CBC and GCM mode?*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2310).
Note that in your implementation for the SHA256 hash it would be more efficient to disable padding and encrypt the *raw* hash.

Comment: For the OP: Read the entire answer. In most cases, these days, AES-GCM is the *easy button*. AES-GCM is widely supported, the checksum (really a MAC) calculation is built-in, and your code will be shorter and easier to maintain.